# Script loader without having to wrap code?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, modular

I would like to keep my JavaScript code modularized in different files, but would like to do so using native JavaScript objects like this:

```
(function ($, _, val) {

   return {
     myTest: 'abc',
     init: function (options) {...}
   };

})(jQuery, _, 'utils/validation');
```

Is there a script loader that can work like this? I've used RequireJS and don't want to wrap all my several files in define/require (although I really like the idea r.Optimizer). Any help or experience would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are meaning, you want to load a separate JavaScript file after the page is loaded.  I have an example that shows how you can have a module spread over multiple files and load additional pieces of that module at later calls.  First, a great summary of different module patterns can be found here: [Adequately Good: Module Patterns](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) and a very nice code snippet that shows a JavaScript loader can be found here: [Loading JS files Asynchronously](http://jeremyhixon.com/snippet/loading-javascript-files-asynchronously/)

My Module's name is `myModule` and it gets three functions during the initial load: `addNumbers()`, `doOperations()`, and `difNumbers()`.  Then after the document is loaded, we store in `tmp` the answer to `doOperations()`.  After that, we want to load the `multiply.js` script so that `myModule` has the `multNumbers()` function, so we call `loadScript()` with the URL to the file, and give it a callback that will print the multiplication to the console.

Here is my code:

**HTML File**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Module Pattern</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script>
         var myModule = (function(my) {
            my.addNumbers = function(a, b) {
               return a + b;
            };
            return my;
         }(myModule || {}));
      </script>
      <script>
         var myModule = (function(my) {
            my.doOperations = function(a, b) {
               return{
                  c: my.addNumbers(a, b),
                  d: my.difNumbers(a, b)
               };
            };
            return my;
         }(myModule || {}));
      </script>
      <script>
         var myModule = (function(my) {
            my.difNumbers = function(a, b) {
               return a - b;
            };
            return my;
         }(myModule || {}));
      </script>
      <script>
         function loadScript(url, success) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = url;
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
                    done = false;
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (!done && (!this.readyState ||
                       this.readyState === "loaded" ||
                       this.readyState === "complete")) {
                  done = true;
                  success();
                  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                  head.removeChild(script);
               }
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         function main() {
            var tmp = myModule.doOperations(5, 6);

            loadScript("multiply.js", function() {
               console.log(myModule.multNumbers(7, 9));
            });
            console.log(tmp.c);
            console.log(tmp.d);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="main();">
      <div>I do operations</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**multiply.js**

```
var myModule = (function(my) {
   my.multNumbers = function(a, b) {
      return a * b;
   };
   return my;
}(myModule || {}));
```